# Dealing with curl to get count for tweets containing that url

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I was using following code to decode the tinyurl from twitter:

```
function MyURLDecode($url) 
{
    $ch = @curl_init($url);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $url_resp = @curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match('/Location:\s+(.*)\n/i', $url_resp, $i);
    if (!isset($i[1]))
    {
    return $url;
    }
   return $i[1];
}
$url = MyURLDecode($url);
```

This using this result to get tweet count value:

```
function get_twitter_url_count($url) {    
    $encoded_url = urlencode($url);    
    $content = @file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $encoded_url);   
    return $content ? json_decode($content)->count : 0;
}
```

Above code works fine. But due to some issue I need to change the `Url Decoding function` which is as below:

```
 function TextAfterTag($input, $tag)
 {
        $result = '';
        $tagPos = strpos($input, $tag);

        if (!($tagPos === false))
        {
                $length = strlen($input);
                $substrLength = $length - $tagPos + 1;
                $result = substr($input, $tagPos + 1, $substrLength); 
        }

        return trim($result);
 }

 function expandUrlLongApi($url)
 {
        $format = 'json';
        $api_query = "http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?" .
                    "url={$url}&response-code=1&format={$format}";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_query );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        $fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $s1=str_replace("{"," ","$fileContents");
        $s2=str_replace("}"," ","$s1");
        $s2=trim($s2);
        $s3=array();
        $s3=explode(",",$s2);
        $s4=TextAfterTag($s3[0],(':'));
        $s4=stripslashes($s4);
        return $s4;
 }
```

This code gives decoded url correctly, infact with better accuracy then previous one but now result of this does not works with this function:

```
function get_twitter_url_count($url) {    
    $encoded_url = urlencode($url);    
    $content = @file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $encoded_url);    
    return $content ? json_decode($content)->count : 0;    
}
```

Rather givig correct count value, it always gives 0.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

full code:

```
<?php

 function TextAfterTag($input, $tag)
 {
        $result = '';
        $tagPos = strpos($input, $tag);

        if (!($tagPos === false))
        {
                $length = strlen($input);
                $substrLength = $length - $tagPos + 1;
                $result = substr($input, $tagPos + 1, $substrLength); 
        }

        return trim($result);
 }

 function expandUrlLongApi($url)
 {
        $format = 'json';
        $api_query = "http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?" .
                    "url={$url}&response-code=1&format={$format}";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_query );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        $fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
/*  preg_match('/Location:\s+(.*)\n/i', $fileContents, $i);
        if (!isset($i[1]))

        {

        return '';

        }

        else
         $fileContents = $i[1]; */
        curl_close($ch);
        $s1=str_replace("{"," ","$fileContents");
        $s2=str_replace("}"," ","$s1");
        $s2=trim($s2);
        $s3=array();
        $s3=explode(",",$s2);
        $s4=TextAfterTag($s3[0],(':'));
        $s4=stripslashes($s4);
        return $s4;
 }

 $url = expandUrlLongApi('http://t.co/SFdM0wjtGA');
 echo "Url is : $url <br/>";
 $url = get_twitter_url_count($url);


?>
```

Comment: Use json_decode($conent,true), this will give you an array.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: can you please elaborate this.? I have added entire code, I appreciate if you help here

Comment: Your code is getting the JSON content via the file_get_contents(), not if you want to convert to array u need to use $data = json_decode($content,true); now if you do a print_r($data) you can see the array with elements and use the one you want to display, in your case it should be something like $data["count"].

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: thanks but still it does not solve issue. I have put full code can you please test it?

Comment: add the code as  $fileContents =  json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);curl_close($ch); Then comment the $s1= ... til return $s4; and do return $fileContents inside the function  expandUrlLongApi(). Then use $fileContents array to find the count. Sorry I cant test this code at my end since this machine does not have my development environment like PHP/CURL etc